# Check if Private Key is password protected using Bash

Tags: bash, openssl, rsa, private-key

I'm looking for a way using a Bash script to detect whether a Private Key file is password protected or not.

I would believe this is possible using OpenSSL using the following command:

```
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -check -noout
```

If I run that I am either presented with "RSA Key ok"(if the private key doesn't have a password set) or a prompt asking me to enter the password (password is set).

Ok, so clearly OpenSSL is detecting there is or isn't a password set on the private key file. I don't want to enter the password or have the user see that, I just want a a simple true/false if a password is set or not so my Bash script can handle that appropriately, ie prompt the user later on to provide the password in another way.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding  more info here because what I am trying to achieve is something a bit different:

I'm scanning over a directory of files (presumed a certificate bundle) and using the bash script to determine the type of each file.

I need to detect the Private Key file and identify it as such, but then I need to separately determine whether a password has been set on it or not.

```
openssl rsa -check -in $FILE &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo -n "Detected Private Key"
   openssl rsa -check -in $FILE -passin pass:1234 &> /dev/null
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
       echo " WITH password"
   else
       echo " WITHOUT password"
   fi
fi
```

The issue I'm having is in my first check I'm using the Key check to see if the file is or isn't a key, but when that check stumbles on a a Key with a password I get prompted to enter the password.

If I pass the -passin option as part of that first check I get a pass/fail but from that pass/fail I cannot determine whether the failure is because there was a password set on the key file or if the keyfile is not a keyfile at all.

I'm trying to build a script that will allow a user to just drop a cert bundle into a folder and have the script sort out what format the files are in and convert them appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a fake password in the command, if the key has no password it will return 0, otherwise the key has a password:

```
openssl rsa -check -in privateKey-enc.key -passin pass:1234 &> /dev/null

echo $?
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe the explanation below is not the best one, but, right now, it might help you.

By default the key file have a standard, if you check the first line (head -1 ), you can see the content is different.

When the key is password-protected the first line is something like:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

- five dashes -----

instead:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You can check this and solve your problem without openssl command:

```
check=$(grep "PRIVATE" $FILE &> /dev/null)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  checkPass=$(grep "ENCRYPTED" $FILE &> /dev/null)
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Private key with password"
  else
    echo "Private Key without password"
  fi
else
  echo "No private key detected"
fi
```

PS. You can do this same check comparing output error of openssl -check command.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this method does work, however I have edited my question above because what I'm trying to achieve is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Please check my edit